# $A$ is diagonalizable over $F$ if and only if the minimal polynomial of $A$ splits over $F$

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization, minimal-polynomials

I came up with a theorem that

> a matrix $A$ is diagonalizable over $F$ if and only if the minimal polynomial of $A$ splits over $F$.

I do not think it is true because we can take the example of the transformation $T(\epsilon_1)=\epsilon_1$ and $T(\epsilon_2)=\epsilon_1+\epsilon_2$ the sheer transformation with minimal polynomial $(t-1)(t-2)$. How can this statement be true then?

Comment: The correct theorem is that $A$ is diagonalizable iff the minimal polynomial splits into *distinct* linear factors. Your counter-example doesn't work, because the minimal polynomial of $T$ is $(t-1)^2$, which doesn't satisfy these hypotheses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question *per se* has been answered; this post answers  various confusions in the comments.

The OP asks how can a minimal polynomial have repeated roots. "how can this be?" is hard to answer, but in fact a minimal polynomial *can* have repeated roots. A constructive answer to "how can this be?" might be possible *if* we knew why someone erroneously thought that a minimal polynomial cannot have repeated roots; then we could explain the error.

I've been asked how one finds the minimal polynomial of  a matrix. Never thought about it.  Two procedures spring to mind:

(i) Say the characteristic  polynomial is $p$. **If** we can factor $p$ then we can do this: Look at all the monic polynomials $q$ that divide $p$, one by one. For each one, check whether $q(A)=0$. The minimal polynomial is the $q$ of minimal degree such that $q(A)=0$.

(ii), Or, simpler but perhaps less efficient: Let $k$ be the minimal positive integer such that $I,A,\dots,A^k$ are linearly dependent.  (To find $k$: test $I,A$ for independence, then test $I,A,A^2$, etc.) A dependence relation $$A^k+c_{k-1}A^{k-1}+\dots+c_0I=0$$gives the minimal  polynomial.

### Example.

Let $A=\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$.

(i) $p(x)=(1-x)^2$. The only non-trivial monic factor of  $p$ is $q(x)=x-1$; since $q(A)\ne0$ the minimal polynomial must be  $p$.

(ii) $I,A$  are certainly independent. But $A^2=\begin{bmatrix}1&2\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$; hence $$A^2+1=2A,$$so the minimal polynomial is $m(x)=x^2-2x+1$.

### The Theorem

Having said all that we may as well give a proof of the theorem.

> > **Theorem.** Suppose $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix over the field $K$. TFAE: (i) $A$ is diagonalizable over $K$ (ii) the minimal polynomial $m$ splits over $K$ annd has distinct roots (iii) there exists a polynomial $q$ such that $q$ splits over $K$, $q$ has distinct roots, and $q(A)=0$.

It's trivial that (ii)) implies (iii). And it's very easy to see that (ii) implies (ii), because if $q$  is as in (iii) then the minimal polynomial $m$ must divide $q$.

If $A$ is actually diagonal then (iii) is clear; hence (iii) holds iif $A$$ is just diagonalizable.

Now assume (iii). Say $q(x)=(x-\lambda_1)\dots(x-\lambda_k)$. Since $q(A)=0$ tthe nullspace of $q(A)$ is $K^n$; so the "kernel lemmma" (below) shows that $K^n$ is the direct sum of the nullspaces of $A-\lambda_jI$. That is, $K^n$  is sppannned by eigenvectors of $A$, so $A$ is diagonalizable.

In general let's write $Z(T)$ for the nullspace of $T$.

> > **Lemma.** If $p$ and $q$ are relatively prime polynomials then $Z(p(A)q(A))=Z(p(A))\oplus Z(q(A))$.

Proof: Since $K[x]$ is a PID there exist polynomials $r$ and $s$ such that
$$pr+qs=1.$$

Suppose $p(A)q(A)x=0$. Now $$x=p(A)r(A)x+q(A)s(A)x,$$and $$q(A)(p(A)r(A)x)=r(A)(p(A)q(A)x)=0.$$Similarly $p(A)(q(A)s(A)x)0,$so $x=p(A)r(A)x+q(A)s(A)x$ shows that $$Z(p(A)q(A))=Z(p(A))+Z(q(A)).$$

Now assume $p(A)x=q(A)x=0$. Then $x=p(A)r(A)x+q(A)s(A)x=0$. So $$Z(p(A))\cap Z(q(A))=\{0\}.$$

Comment: Isn't there any simpler process?

Comment: I know it is a silly question,still...

Comment: @KishalaySarkar Simpler? Method (ii) is trivial. (Also method (ii) is _obvious_ from the simple proof that $A$ is annihhilated by some polynomial.)

Comment: Sorry I got it now.

Answer (score 1):

The proper statement is that $A$ is diagonalizable iff its minimal polynomial splits and has distinct roots.

In particular the minimal polynomial (thanks to David for pointing out my mistake) of your example is $p(x) = (1 - x)^2$, which does not have distinct roots and so is not a counterexample.

Comment: What is the proof of this theorem?

Comment: Theorem 4.11 [here](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/minpolyandappns.pdf)

Comment: what about $$\begin{bmatrix}2 & 1 & 1\\1 & 2 & 1\\-2 & -2 & -1\\\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: this is not diagonalizable.

Comment: @KishalaySarkar What about it? The theorem is a theorem. It's true. So  if you think that matrix is a counterexample you're wrong.  We can't find the error in your calculations since you didn't show us your calculations; in any case you should find the error yourself....

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich This matrix has only 2 independent eigenvector when the underlying field is R

Comment: @nbritten in your answer to the question you are saying characteristic polynomial is $(1-x)^2$ ok,but its minimal polynomial is $(1-x)$ right,which has no repreated factors,how can minimal polynomial have repeated factors?

Comment: @KishalaySarkar _If_ you're correct about that then the matrix is not diaggonalizable. Again, so what? That would give a counterexample if the theorem said every matrix was diagonalizable.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich But the matrix has characteristic polynomial $(1-x)^3$,so minimal polynomial is $(1-x)$ having no repeated root.Again one second,how can a minimal polynomial have repeated roots?Does there exist minimal polynomial with repeated roots?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Minimal polynomial is the lowest degree monic annihilating polynomial,if I get (1-x),then how can minimal polynomial be $(1-x)^2$,the characteristic polynomial is $(1-x)^2$.

Comment: @KishalaySarkar Why do you keep saying the minimal polynomial is $(1-x)$? That's simply not so - if $A$ is the matrix above then $A-I\ne0$.  "How can a minimal poynomial have repeated roots?" Well, we have an example. Why do you think a minimal polynomial cannot have repeated roots?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I am just newly studying minimal polynomial,I have seen in some cases that suppose characteristic polynomial is $(x-1)(x-2)^2$ then then minimal polynomial is $(x-1)(x-2)$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich What is the actual process of obtaining minimal polynomial?

Comment: @KishalaySarkar Yes, it can happen  that the  characteristic polynomial is $(x-1)(x-2)^2$ and the minimal polynomial is $(x-1)(x-2)$. **So what???** That's  a different matrix. If $A$ is the matrix in your comment and $m(x)=x-1$ **what** is $m(A)$???

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I am sorry for the misunderstanding,what is actually the process of obtaining the minimal polynomial?

Comment: @KishalaySarkar See the Answer I just posted...